# Flux interval ticks on new threads

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

I would like to have a continuously running job with Flux which calls a service and processes its response. The processing could be slower than the frequency of the service call. I have a sample code to do it, but it doesn't do what I would like to achieve.

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(1), Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .doOnNext(counter -> something())
    .onErrorContinue(...)
    .doOnComplete(...)
    .subscribe();
```

So the problem is if the tick occurs in every second, but the something() needs 5 sec to complete then something() is called in every 5 sec not in every 1 sec. How to modify the code that every something() gets an own thread (from a bounded thread pool)? I have tested that every subscriber gets a dedicated thread, so I could increase the processing with multiple (fixed) subscribers, but I would like to make it more dynamical.

Thanks!

Comment: is `something()` a blocking call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
        Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(1), Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .onBackpressureDrop()
                .flatMap(counter -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                    something();
                    return counter; // simply to justify the callable, in case something has return type void.
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
                .onErrorContinue(...)
                .doOnComplete(...)
                .subscribe();
```

The `subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` will execute the Mono on an unbounded thread pool. It will also allow you to further continue the stream with more operations.

Comment: I will try this out!

Comment: Yes, it's working, so right now I don't know which solution is better, yours or mine :)

Comment: Just to add - in case you want a bounded thread pool you can replace `parallel()` with `boundedElastic`, since you mentioned that you'd prefer a bounded pool.

Answer (score 0):

I did more investigation and I came up with this code:

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(1), Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .doOnNext(counter -> something())
    .sequential()
    .onErrorContinue(...)
    .doOnComplete(...)
    .subscribe();
```

Seems like it does what I wanted.